# How to ignore files with git - without adding to .gitignore

Tags: git

I think that the answer to this question is probably that it can't be done but I would be interested to hear any solutions or workarounds that people use.

The situation is that I have a seed npm project. Whenever my team wants to start a new project they clone this project and use it as a basis for the new work.

In this seed project when I do `npm install` I get a `package-lock.json` file. I do not want to check this file in as I do not want to lock projects that are based on the seed project to the dependency versions of the seed project.

However, I do not want to add this file to the `.gitignore` file as if I do that the `.gitignore` file would also be copied and then the lock file would also be ignored in the project that is based on the seed.

I hope that I have explained that well enough.

Comment: Adding the package-lock.json to git is recommended.

Comment: I know but not in this case. The seed project will never be released or built. It will only be cloned to be built as another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create local ignore rules that are not shared as part of the repository content.  Of course each clone that needs the rule has to be configured individually, but for your use case that's probably a good trade-off.

The file `.git/info/exlcude` works just like `.gitignore` but is loacl.